# Botão aciona o método do seu container

Tags: jquery, html

Criei uma aba que abre e fecha usando jQuery e estou tendo alguns problemas para fechá-la:

**HTML**

```
<div id="aba" style="position: absolute">
    <img src="#"/>
    <span id="fechar">X</span>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var fechado = true;
$("#aba").click(function(){
    if (fechado){
        $("#aba").animate({left: "10px"});
        fechado = false;
    }
});
$("#fechar").click(function(){
    if (fechado == false){
        $("#aba").animate({left: "0px"});
        fechado = true;
    }
});
```

O que acontece é que quando eu clico no fechar, ele, provavelmente, entende que está clicando no abrir também; ou seja, ele fecha e abre logo em seguida. Tentei usar uma *flag*, mas sem sucesso.
O real problema é que não posso tirar o botão de fechar de dentro da aba.

Comment: Acho que o erro está em não mudar o valor da variável `fechado` , tente adicionar abaixo do `$("#aba").animate({left: "10px"});` um `fechado = false`

Comment: Como o span está abaixo da DIV, possivelmente ele está sobreposto por ela, ou seja, você acha que está clicando no span mas está clicando na DIV. Tente mudar a localização ou usar z-index.

Comment: @HermesAutran, falha minha, esqueci de colocar no código, mas existe.

Comment: @Ascension, não funcionou.

Comment: Outra coisa, você não deveria tirar o `animate` da `$("#aba")` ao invés do `$("#fechar")`. Como o `span` está dentro da `div`, se você esconde-la tudo vai se esconder também. Tente `$("#aba").animate({left: "0px"});` ao invés de `$("#fechar").animate({left: "0px"});`

Comment: Novamente, está como fechar a aba, escrevi errado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como a div `#fechar` está dentro da div `#aba`, o browser entende que quando você clica no `#fechar`, você pretende clicar tanto nele quanto no elemento que está "atrás" dele, no caso, a `#aba`. O que você deve fazer pra evitar isso é **parar a propagação do evento de clique**. No código, isso fica assim:

```
var fechado = true;
$("#aba").click(function(){
    if (fechado){
        $("#aba").animate({left: "10px"});
        fechado = false;
    }
});

$("#fechar").click(function(e){ // Recebe o evento como parâmetro do listener
    if (fechado == false){
        $("#aba").animate({left: "0px"}); // Você tem que fechar a #aba, não o #fechar
        fechado = true;
    }
    e.stopPropagation(); // Manda o navegador parar de "subir o evento" para os próximos elementos.
});
```

Note também que ao invés de fechar a aba, você estava "fechando" o seu botão que era só um trigger: `$("#fechar").animate({left: "0px"});`.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/98cHN/1) (abra o console para ver as mensagens de teste)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Quanto ao "fechar o botão", foi uma falha minha, aqui eu escrevi `#fechar`, mas lá no código está `#aba`.